# Javascript send list to asmx service

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays, asp.net-ajax, asmx

I create an asmx service in .net web forms as below. The AddUsers method accept List model.

```
namespace ProjectName.AsmxServices.Test
 {

[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.ComponentModel.ToolboxItem(false)]

[ScriptService]
 public class Test: System.Web.Services.WebService
   {
    [WebMethod]
    public void AddUsers(List<UserDetail> userList)
    {
        // Add User List
    }

   // Here is my model
   public class UserDetail
    {
        public int Id{ get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Surname{ get; set; }
        public DateTime BirthDate { get; set; }
    }
   }
 }
```

Now, I want to post List model in Javascript. But how can I create this model as list in javascript ?

```
         $("#addUsers").click(function () {

         var data = ??  **How can I create a List<UserDetail> model.**

         $.ajax({
            url: '../AsmxServices/Test.asmx/AddUsers',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            data: data
            success: function (result) {
                console.log("Good job!");
            },
            error: function (result) {
                console.log("Failed");
            }

        });
    });
```

I want to create this modelList hardcoded now. Then I will change my code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
var usersList = 
    {
        userList: 
            [
                {Id: 1, Name: "name1"}, 
                {Id: 2, Name: "name2"}
            ]
    };

var data = JSON.stringify(usersList);
```

Comment: Thank you :) It worked. I just change the data (JSON.stringify(data))

Comment: Great! I added it to the answer.